# Finding $b-a$ for positive integer $a$, $b$ satisfying $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{3x^2+12x+16}{(x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)( x+4))^3}=\frac1{4(a!)^b}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

> $$
> \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}\frac{3x^{2} + 12x + 16}
> {\left[\vphantom{A^{A}}x\left(x + 1\right)\left(x + 2\right)
> \left(x + 3\right)\left(x + 4\right)\right]^{\, 3}} =
> \frac{1}{4\left(a!\right)^{b}}
> $$
>
> Compute $b-a$ if $b$ and $a$ are positive integers.

I asked my teacher to help me in solving this sum. But, unfortunately, he said I can't. it is a very hard question, So, I hope you can help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Finding the answer is much easier than designing the question.

Comment: Nice problem ...

Comment: Where did you find this Problem ,

Answer (score 5):

The answer is $\color{green}{-1}$.

Indeed, the sum converges very quickly (the terms are $\Theta(x^{-13})$) and the inverses of the partial sums are

$$55741.9354839\\
55312.3888560\\
55297.2897327\\
55296.1612133\\
55296.0276428\\
55296.0059708\\
55296.0015387\\
55296.0004559\\
55296.0001513\\
55296.0000551\\
\cdots$$

Obviously, this tends to $4\cdot4!^3$.

Comment: you mean the answer is -1

Comment: Unexpectedly, yes. Fixing.

Comment: not an algerbraic way :/ but nice breakthru

Comment: @Idle001: it doesn't need to be much algebraic as it is given that $a$ and $b$ are integers. For rigor, one should show that among the few possibilities for this order of magnitude, no other can be that close. The most "dangerous" is $4\cdot5!^2=57600$.

Comment: Speaking of unexpected, the partial sums also [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%283y%5E2%2B4%29%2F%28y%28y%5E2-1%29%28y%5E2-4%29%29%5E3%29+for+y+%3D+3+to+n) a surprisingly "nice" form, where $y=x+2$ and $M=(n - 1) n (n + 1) (n + 2)\,$.

$$
\sum_{y=3}^n \frac{3 y^2 + 4}{\left(y (y^2 - 1) (y^2 - 4)\right)^3} 
 = \frac{(n - 2) (n + 3) (n^2 + n + 4)(M^2 + 24 M + 576)}{55296\, M^3}
$$